# handling push notifications to different views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I receive my push notification successfully but when I tap on it, it simply takes me to first view when my app loads.

I want the user to go to specific views depending on the push notification because the user will be receiving many different push notifications (1 for each soccer team, hence possiblity of many different views).

So example: I have a view controller called manchesterUnitedView and somebody just scored so the user receives a push notification for that particular view. When they press it, I want it to take them to the manchesterUnitedView.

Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Comment: To do what you want, you have to create you of the launch, which procedures you Mandino directly to the controller of your interest. Unfortunately, the Push Notification is only accessible by Appdelegate so this should be the only way.

Comment: @WhiteTiger Thanks for the reply... Sorry I think you have some spelling mistakes, can you please try to explain again?

Comment: I'm sorry for my English, however relied on methods that you create you will allow to display the reference. then read the value of the method calls push-screen that shows you the screen you requested.

Comment: @Alex G have you got the answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: @JasonZhao No unfortunately I have not. Been searching like crazy. How about you?

Comment: @AlexG I'm still working on it. Anything I got, will update you.

Comment: @AlexG See this question you asked [Push view from push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345624/push-view-from-push-notification). I'll try it later...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the payload of the notification to pass the information you need to the app, then retrieve it and use it when the app is launched as a result of the user tapping on a notification.

To do this just add a custom dictionary to the JSON payload of the notification and add the information you need to pass to the app there.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) for details on the payload format.

You can then retrieve your custom dictionary  when the app is launched in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method implementation of your `UIApplicationDelegate` and use it to initialize your application state.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for documentation of how to retrieve the payload in your UIApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in this.

The following should work:
I receive the Push on my iPhone and after clicking the "View" Button the App should open, and then i can read the full message.

just like here on this site (bottom): http://www.myfitapp.de/fitnessstudio-app/push-nachrichten/