# Push view from push notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I receive my notifications successfully for iOS 5. I want to be able send users to a specific view when they swipe or tap the push notification in the notification centre.

The view controller (view) I want the user to go to opposed to just the start of my app is the "groceryStoreViewController". I have read that this is done in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didReceiveRemoteNotification but I am not sure.

If anyone knows how to do this, I would really appreciate it since it has really been a struggle.

Thanks

**EDIT**

So the issue is that I want a specific view controller to be opened when the user taps a notification but I also want the UITabBar to remain. I have not successfully been able to do this and it has something to do with me displaying the subview I believe. Please let me know what you think and thank you so much.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] init] autorelease];

 exploreViewController *view1 = [[exploreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"exploreViewController" bundle:nil];
view1.title= @"Explore";

Upcoming *view2 = [[Upcoming alloc] initWithNibName:@"Upcoming" bundle:nil];
view2.title = @"Upcoming";

TipsViewController *view3 = [[TipsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TipsView" bundle:nil];
view3.title = @"Tips";

UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2];
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view3];

[view1 release];
[view2 release];
[view3 release];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nil];
self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] init] autorelease];

[nav1 release];
[nav2 release];
[nav3 release];


if (launchOptions != nil)
{  
NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSLog(@"Launched from push notification");
//Accept push notification when app is not open
if (remoteNotif) {      

 NSDictionary *alertBody = [remoteNotif objectForKey:@"loc-key"];

 self.window.rootViewController = nav2;  //this is what I want displayed when tapped but also maintain tab bar controller
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  }
}
else {

    //Go here if just loading up normally without push
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
  return YES;

}
```

Comment: question is not well defined.!

Comment: @hp iOS Coder: Not every user here on stack can speak english very well. so please be kind and give it a shot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.  You can check whether the app launched because of a notification and set the appropriate viewController to display.

Something like:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // other stuff

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Launched from push notification");
        NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        // Do something with the notification dictionary
        self.myViewController = [LaunchFromNotificationViewController alloc] init];
    } else {
        self.myViewController = [OrdinaryLaunchViewController alloc] init];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.myViewController;
    [self.windows makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example? Would mean a lot. Thanks

Comment: @ jcm: I tried to use your code with the new storyboard feature. the delegation to the view does not work.. do you have experience in storyboard?

Comment: @jcm seems not work, I run your code. the launchOptions always == nil even when I open app by notification...

Comment: @AlexisW no storyboard experience, sorry.  We don't use it.

Comment: @JasonZhao Post a question and I'll take a look.

Comment: @jcm sorry, it's my misunderstanding. `if (launchOptions != nil) {` will only work when app is close, not running in background. Thanks @jcm

Comment: @JasonZhao ok, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @jcm Sorry for the late reply, I was not aware you had given me an example. I want to thank you for doing this but I was wondering if you could check my code since you have quite a good understanding of this it seems. I have put new code under my edited question. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @AlexG What exactly is going wrong?  Could you edit the code for formatting and cut out the unrelated stuff?  I'm having a hard time reading it, thanks.