# Jumping to a view in storyboard with push notification

Tags: xcode, storyboard, apple-push-notifications

I have a project which dont have a navigation control but has a storyboard. I can receive the Push Notification to my app. After the user click the Notification message and lunch the apps, I want it to jump to one of the views in the storyboard to display the details of the messaged fetched from the internet.

Any idea how to do that??

I have red a lot here about the same problem - like [Push view from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345624/push-view-from-push-notification) -  but all of them either works without Storyboard, or with storyboard with navigation.

Thank you in advance.